# Need to filter IPs in Google Analytics

Tags: regex, filter, google-analytics

I need to filter, 213.190.149.120 - 213.190.149.127 inclusive

Anyone know if there is a regular expression I can use to do this?

Thanks,
C

Answer (score 1):

If you need a strict regular expression, don't forget that `.` matches any character, so

```
^213.190.149.(1(2[0-7]))$
```

will match "213d190c149a125" for example, which is not what you want.

On top of what, you're capturing each of the 3 digits, which is resource consuming for no apparent reason. A simple yet stricter regex would be closer to what @Marc suggested:

```
^213\.190\.149\.12[0-7]$
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how Google Analytics expects the expression but this would be a valid regualar expression for your request:

213.190.149.12[0-7]

Comment: ..except that without start and end anchors and not escaping the dots, it will accept for instance "blahblah213a190b149c120moreblah"

Answer (score 0):

Okay.Found this [link](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55572)...

and it outputs...

```
^213\.190\.149\.(1(2[0-7]))$
```

Very handy for anyone else looking to do this.